# 301 redirects for language versions

Tags: seo, redirect

We have a website with lots of content (couple of thousand articles). The site has two language versions: English and Finnish.

Most of the time an article has two version of it like: example.com/article and example.fi/artikkeli.

We are going to remove Finnish version of this site and I was thinking that is it a good or bad practice to make 301 redirects from those articles to their corresponding English counterparts? I'm thinking this mostly from SEO aspect.

Answer (score -1):

Making a 301 redirect is in fact a good practice. Because in this way you tell the search engines and bots that it has permanently moved . It doesn't impact indexing of pages and provide consistent performance and SEO value . Here is a good article that can further help you understand which kind of redirect is a good practice or not . https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection . Let me know if that helped you :)